# How to use session with angularJS and PHP backend

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I'm developing an AngularJs application with PHP backend, I implemented the authentication step, and now I'm trying to display data of authenticated user in another view after authentication.

I used session token to display user data in other view but Even if I did what I read in some tutorials about sessions and tokens more than two weeks, I still can't display user data. And I get this error in display.php file:

> Undefined index: token

How can I manage this problem?

**login.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
  }

       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';

$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT Name,Adresse FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the content of "token" in the $_SESSION, but you must add a check beforehand to ensure that "token" is in the array named $_SESSION.
You encountered this error because your session does not hold any "token" data (a var_dump / print_r on $_SESSION should confirm that).

Add the following:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
  // Output an error message, or take a specific action to handle this case.
  return;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but if I undestand our idea, is that the session does not hold any "token"!! how can I make it hold it!!!

Comment: You could start checking the return value of mysqli_query when updating the database to ensure that everything went as desired. You can also print_r / var_dump (as said) $_SESSION on the display.php page to look into it and know what is stored.
Are you sure you went to your login page prior to trying to use the display page ?

Comment: yes thie login step is working fine, when I click on submit, it redirect me to the other page where user data is supposed to be displayed, but it return nothing